# Speeding up an SSIS data import

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am using this resource to help speed up the process of deleting records from CRM:

http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2012/02/improve-crm-data-load-performance-by.html

And specifically this section:

[image]

I am trying to follow this advice:

> In order to make full use of the BDD component, you need to increase
>   the connection limit that is imposed by Microsoft .NET framework,
>   which is a maximum of 2 connections per host (e.g. server) for service
>   calls as far as CRM platform is concerned. In order to overwrite this
>   limit, you need to modify DTExec.exe.config and
>   DtsDebugHost.exe.config files under DTS\binn folder by adding the
>   following connectionManagement section.

But I am unable to find the config files. I don't know so much about deploying the solution; however, even after trying to deploy it, I did not see a config file being created:

[image]

Here is the output I got from SSIS:

[image]

In case this is of any help, here's what my topology looks like": [image]

**How do I speed up the deletion of records out of CRM using SSIS?**

Comment: You need to edit the files in `DTS\binn` as specified. The config files will not exist in your SSIS Packages\Delete Accounts folder

Comment: @billinkc could you please tell me where that would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dtexec.exe and DtsDebugHost.exe will live in the DTS\Version\Binn folder where Version 
- 110 = SQL Server 2012 
- 100 = SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2
- 90 = SQL Server 2005

For 64 bit machines, there will be two flavors of the executable. Assuming installation to the default location, you may find them at

### 32 bit location

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn

### 64 bit location

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn

For 32 bit machines, please destroy your machines and update to 64 bit architecture. That said, your file locations will be the same as the 64 bit locations above.

Comment: thanks so much! i am unable to save this file: http://screencast.com/t/wRRaC44yET

Comment: You will need to stop any SSIS packages currently executing in Visual Studio/SSDT/BIDS for that to go away

Comment: i restarted my computer, there's nothing running that would require those dtsx files, no visual studio running, yet it still gives me that message